# How to @suppress multiple warnings with Closure Compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, google-closure-compiler, suppress

It's possible to suppress warnings on a per-file basis with Google's Closure Compiler via the [`@suppress` annotation](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings).  However, it doesn't seem to be possible to suppress multiple warnings at the same time--for example the `globalThis` and `checkVars` warnings.  I tried both

```
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @suppress {globalThis checkVars}
 */
```

and

```
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @suppress {globalThis,checkVars}
 */
```

but both result in the `@suppress` annotation being ignored.  Multiple `@suppress` lines also do not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Separate the types with the pipe character (eg: '|').

```
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @suppress {globalThis|checkVars}
 */
```

Comment: You can also separate with comma: `@suppress {globalThis, checkVars}`
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings#suppress-tags